# Deserialize JSON from HttpWebRequest Response Stream with progress

Tags: .net, json, httpwebrequest

I download large amounts of data using a HttpWebRequest. As suggested [on their website](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) I pass the response stream directly to the JsonSerializer.Deserialize method.

Now I want to report progress during the download. There are enough sources on the web [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806988/342594) that show how to do it.

My problem is, I don't know how to combine those two features.

My first idea was to download and report the progress, then rewind the stream and pass it to the Deserialize method, but that doesn't work, because the stream is not seekable.

My second idea (which I haven't tried yet) is to read chunks of data from the response stream to report progress and write these chunks to a MemoryStream. Then I would rewind the MemoryStream to the Deserialize method. That *could* work, but I would end up with the complete data in memory so the performance gain as described [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) is lost. So I might as well forget about the memory stream and read everything to a string.

I would be happy, if somebody could give me some hints how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an implementation of `Stream` (let's call it `ProgressStream`) that wraps the `HttpWebResponse` stream and passes all `Read` requests to it, while tracking the total number of bytes that have been read. Then pass that `ProgressStream` instance to `Deserialize`.

The Json.NET `Deserialize` method will call `Read` on your `ProgressStream`, which will then call `Read` on the underlying web response stream. There will be no inefficient buffering because the bytes will be immediately passed back to Json.NET. You will be able to track how many bytes have been read so far; if you know the `Content-Length` of the response, you can calculate a percentage downloaded.

Here's a sample implementation: https://erictummers.com/2011/02/15/upload-progress-in-wcf/

Here's another one that's internal to ASP.NET itself: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Handlers/ProgressStream.cs

And a third one: http://mel-green.com/2010/01/progressstream/

Comment: That sounds great. It's too late to try it right now, but I will try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, just had some time to take a look at the links you posted. I ended up using the implementation from the first link (check out the codeproject link for a full example). The third one didn't work, because accessing the stream's position wasn't supported for my stream. Thanks @Bradley Grainger